# Convert python mutable namedlist to immutable namedtuple

Tags: python-3.x, immutability, mutable, namedtuple

Is there a way to convert or make a copy of a python mutable namedlist to an immutable namedtuple?

**EDIT based on the comments:**

I have a namedlist filled with values

```
>>> from namedlist import namedlist
>>> nl = namedlist('myList', 'a b c d')

>>> L = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
>>> D = dict(zip(nl._fields,L))
>>> NL = nl(**D)

>>> NL
myList(a='A', b='B', c='C', d='D')
```

This mutable namedlist NL can be changed like this:

```
>>> NL.a = 'X'

>>> NL
myList(a='X', b='B', c='C', d='D')
```

Then I also create a nametuple with same fields

```
from collections import namedtuple
nt = namedtuple('myTuple', nl._fields)
```

**Question**

Is it now possible to create an immutable namedtuple NT with filled values based on values in the namedlist NL ?

**ANSWER from the comments:**

Use:

```
>>> NT = nt(*NL)

>>> NT
myTuple(a='X', b='B', c='C', d='D')
```

This immutable namedtuple cannot be changed:

```
>>> NT.a = 'Y'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean the package installed by `pip install namedlist`, then if you have a namedlist defined like this:

```
from namedlist import namedlist
nl = namedlist('myList', 'a b c d')
```

You can make a corresponding namedtuple:

```
from collections import namedtuple
nt = namedtuple('myTuple', 'a b c d')
# or, you if you want to copy the names
nt = namedtuple('myTuple', nl._fields)
```

An example of use might look like this:

```
l = nl(1,2,3,4)      # myList(a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4)
t = nt(*l)           # myTuple(a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4)
```

Comment: l = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

Comment: That's a list with four elements, not a `namedlist`.  Converting this list to a (standard) tuple can be done as simply as `t = tuple(l)`, but that's not a namedtuple.

Comment: Sorry for my first comment. I'm not used to the 'comment editor'
    from namedlist import namedlist
    nl = namedlist('myList', 'a b c d')

    from collections import namedtuple
    nt = namedtuple('myTuple', nl._fields)

    # I can set values in the namedlist like this: 
    L = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
    D = dict(zip(nl._fields,L))
    NL = nl(**D)
    NL

    # This namedlist NL can also be changed like this:
    NL.a = 'X'
    NL

    #Is it possible to create a namedtuple NT with filled values based on values in the namedlist NL

Comment: I still don't understand the 'comment editor', sorry

Comment: If I correctly understand what you put in your comment, the answer is `NT=nt(*NL)`